# Python threading library: code executes linearly and not in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I want to run two threads in parallel (on python3.6), which works for following code example:

```
import threading
from time import sleep

# use Thread to run def in background
# Example:
def func1():
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        print("Working")

def func2():
    while True:
        sleep(2)
        print("Working2")


Thread(target = func1).start()
Thread(target = func2).start()
```

but it does not work for threading.Thread:

```
import threading
from time import sleep
# use Thread to run def in background
# Example:
def func1():
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        print("Working")

def func2():
    while True:
        sleep(2)
        print("Working2")


x = threading.Thread(target=func1())
y = threading.Thread(target=func2())
x.start()
y.start()
```

I would like to use the latter option to check if x or y are still alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between `Thread(target = func1)` (first code) and `Thread(target=func1())` (second code):

- the first one passes the *function object* to `Thread`
- the second one *executes* the function (because you *called* it with `func1()`) and passes its *return value* to `Thread`

Since you want *the threads* to call your functions, don't call them:

```
x = threading.Thread(target=func1)
y = threading.Thread(target=func2)
x.start()
y.start()
```